# generate ajax postback for only one updatepannel in javascript

Tags: asp.net, ajax

when I click a button the content inside my updatepannel changes. The id of the button is set as a trigger for the updatepannel, so that the other updatepannels are not affected. 
How can I replace the buttonclick event with a page load event?

Is there a way to specify the pageload javasript event as a trigger for the updatepannel?

Comment: Is there a reason why you can't just do the work in Page_Load?

Comment: Do you mean pageLoad() like in the answer ? No there isn't. But don't I need to call this function somewhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no way to register `pageLoad()` as a trigger, but you can call `__doPostBack()` in that function to force your `UpdatePanel` to refresh itself. However, that will cause an infinite loop if you're not careful, because `pageLoad()` is also called when partial postbacks complete.

One way around that problem is to set a flag before refreshing the panel, and persist that flag in the `window` object so it survives partial postbacks:

```
function pageLoad()
{
   if (!this.panelRefreshed) {
       this.panelRefreshed = true;
       __doPostBack("yourUpdatePanelClientID", "");
   }
}
```